# Remote Desktop won't start on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I'm not sure why, but my remote desktop connection app won't start.

Windows Event is:

> Windows cannot access the file C:\Windows\System32\mstscax.dll for one
>   of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network
>   connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage
>   drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows
>   closed the program Remote Desktop Connection because of this error.
>
> Program: Remote Desktop Connection
>   File: C:\Windows\System32\mstscax.dll
>
> The error value is listed in the Additional Data section. User Action
>
> 1. Open the file again. This situation might be a temporary problem that corrects itself when the program runs again.
> 2. If the file still cannot be accessed and
>
>    - It is on the network, your network administrator should verify that there is not a problem with the network and that the server can be
>        contacted.
>    - It is on a removable disk, for example, a floppy disk or CD-ROM, verify that the disk is fully inserted into the computer.
> 3. Check and repair the file system by running CHKDSK. To run CHKDSK, click Start, click Run, type CMD, and then click OK. At the command
>      prompt, type CHKDSK /F, and then press ENTER.
> 4. If the problem persists, restore the file from a backup copy.
> 5. Determine whether other files on the same disk can be opened. If not, the disk might be damaged. If it is a hard disk, contact your
>      administrator or computer hardware vendor for further assistance.
>
> Additional Data
>
> Error value: C00000B5
>   Disk type: 3

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: And the file is there?

Comment: Have you tried running the sys file checker? `sfc /SCANNOW` from a cmd prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the file with a good copy from another PC. If that still doesn't work try doing a full repair of the windows install, not recovery console, a full repair. This may take a little longer but will almost certainly fix the problem and you won't lose any data or settings. If you don't have another 7 PC you can install [RDP 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084) on a vista or xp machine and copy the dll from that pc, it is basically the same thing. My last idea would be to install your own MSTC, this is fairly easy and in fact company's like AEP's Netilla will push there own MSTSC client on you as not to interfere with the default windows one. It's a total of 5 reg keys that need to be added and 4 files. I can help you with this if need be.